# Does $P|_{\mathcal{F}}=Q$ imply $E_P[X]=E_Q[X]$ for $\mathcal{F}$-measurable $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

Consider probability spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$ and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, Q)$ with the properties $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{G}$ and $P|_{\mathcal{F}}=Q$.

Let $X$ be a $Q$-integrable (and $\mathcal{F}$-measurable) random variable. Is it true, that

$$E_P[X]=E_Q[X]\quad ?$$

I feel like this should be true. I think there is an approximation of $X$ with simple functions on $\mathcal{F}$ and because of the fact, that $P(F)=Q(F)$ for any $F\in\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. In fact, it is true when $0 \leq X \leq \infty$ is $F$-measurable, which then implies it is true for integrable $F$-measurable $X$ since $X = X^+ - X^-$. To prove for $0 \leq X \leq \infty$, you can prove it for simple functions on $F$ and then take a sequence of nonnegative simple functions $\phi_n \nearrow X$ and use the monotone convergence theorem.